# Python Function App connections using managed identity

Tags: python, azure-functions

Unable to set up connection information for service bus with Python Azure functions for managed identity.

I have the following settings in function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "myinputqueue",
      "connection": "MySvcConn"
    }
  ]
}
```

and in Application settings in Azure portal i have set

```
"MySvcConn__fullyQualifiedNamespace":"mysvcns.servicebus.windows.net"
```

I get the message

```
"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus: Value for the connection string 
parameter name 'mysvcns.servicebus.windows.net' was not found. (Parameter 'connectionString').
```

Version of Runtime used ~4

host.json configuration

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Comment: could you check the install bundle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-python#install-bundle ?

Comment: The azure portal deploys a older version of extension "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)" where as the recommended version is "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)". How to update extensions

Comment: You should be able to edit the host.json locally then redeploy.

Answer (score 1):

- To connect to service bus using a managed Identity we have first add `servicebus data receiver` role to the access control.
- Then add the connection setting to application setting under the name
  `ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace` and add the connection value as `<Name_of_servicebus>.servicebus.windows.net`.
- The above setting will connect the function app to the service bus using managed identity without the use of connection string.

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial-2)

Comment: based on the answer i modified the function.json. Removed connection from this file. Now i get this error Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK 
ServiceBus connection string 'AzureWebJobsServiceBus' is missing or empty. My app setting have a "ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace" and the value set to 'mysvcns.servicebus.windows.net"

Comment: try using ServiceBusConnection:fullyQualifiedNamespace  instead of  ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace

Comment: application settings does not allow ":" in the name field. Only allowed chars are alphabets, number and "_"

Comment: I just  added the ServiceBusConnection:fullyQualifiedNamespace in a function app  https://i.imgur.com/hDx9Kiz.png

Comment: me not able to https://imgur.com/fzPr22A

Comment: i get it , you are using c# functions, i am using python runtime for functions. You are able to add due that. Python runtime does not allow

Comment: @user2603610 - please refrain from posting lots of follow-up detail here in comments. Edit your question instead. Also, please be sure to include properly-formatted text, not images of text.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure this out, need to set up application settings in function app for the following

```
ServiceBusConnection__clientID:<managedidenity client id>
ServiceBusConnection__credential:managedidentity
ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace:<servicebusname>.servicebus.windows.net
```

"ServiceBusConnection" in the above settings being the connection name in function.json file.